# How to select all hours in a day by dragging down in fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, scroll, fullcalendar, scrollbar

I am trying to select all hours in a day using mouse , but scroll bar not going down. Please check the image below. Is it possible in fullcalender that all hours can select and scroll bar automatically go down according to mouse movement.? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done using the [dragScroll](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/dragScroll/) option, according to the documentation it should be enabled by default.

Comment: Thanks. It is working. But there still problem exist. When scrolling down the scroll bar without arrow marked in the image , ie main scroll bar should go down accordingly.

Comment: @SHADOWS I'm pretty sure that's not how browsers work. If you're scrolling within an inner scroll bar, then only that bar scrolls. Not really an issue specific to this plugin. Happy to be contradicted, but that's what I can observe.